# scala pattern matching for comprehension

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, for-comprehension

In scala can you have a for comprehension that iterates through a List of objects and then makes a Arrays of values based on the type of one of the attributes of the elements?  So assume I have a list of elements and each element has an attribute, and the attribute could be different types...

```
for (element <- elementList) element.attribute match {
 case a: Type1 => "Type1"
 case a => "All Types"
}
```

And then the resulting Array would be an array with values like

```
Array("Type1", "Type1", "All Types", "Type1", "All Types", "All Types", "All Types", "All Types")
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What  I wrote doesn't work.  The question is how to make the Array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you have to do is `yield` a result... And possibly convert to an `Array`.

```
(for (element <- elementList) yield element.attribute match {
  case a: Type1 => "Type1"
  case a => "All Types"
}).toArray
```

Answer (score 3):

Why you don't use a map function from `List(Element)` to `List(String)`?

If you whant to get an Array from `List(String)` you have the function `toArray`.

Comment: so this would be merely: `elementList map { _.attribute match { /* cases */ } }.toArray`, right?